# Stick Footer no longer works in complex liquid design

Tags: html, css

I have a liquid design that has three major sections top, content and footer.

The top has a fixed sized logo with heading and navbar that should fill the remaining right side of the page.

The content section leaves the space under the logo blank and has two columns that should fill the remaining space evenly (50% each).

The footer should stick to the bottom of the page, period!

I can get the pieces to work individually, but when I try to combine them into one page, the footer won't stay down, if the content of the columns is 'long'. Clearly I'm missing something, but no one else around here can see it either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Final Design</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 9.6" />
    <link href="final.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="totalContentWrap">
      <div id="topContentWrap">
          <div id="logo">
              Logo goes here.
          </div>
          <div id="topContent">
              <div id="heading">
                  Heading goes here.
              </div>
              <div id="navbar">
                  Navbar goes here.
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="contentWrap">
          <div id="blank">
              Nothing goes here.
          </div>
          <div id="mainContent">
              <div id="contentLeft">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed dui enim. Aenean mattis massa nec quam viverra ut consectetur turpis lobortis. Aliquam vitae elit erat, ac iaculis nunc. Maecenas fringilla ornare blandit. Nunc fermentum bibendum mattis. Curabitur elementum commodo volutpat. Ut dapibus odio sit amet leo euismod in viverra mi cursus. Quisque commodo velit accumsan lorem sagittis dignissim fermentum nisl dapibus. Praesent in augue sem, id viverra enim.
                      </p>
                      <p>Fusce scelerisque, ante in lacinia cursus, sem nulla suscipit magna, at posuere magna tellus sit amet erat. Vivamus erat enim, elementum sed molestie id, mollis eu dolor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque interdum rutrum nisl in aliquet. Nunc bibendum eros non purus gravida venenatis. Duis dictum commodo lorem non sodales. Nunc mattis hendrerit suscipit. Fusce lacinia, mauris a iaculis pharetra, ante massa bibendum augue, nec tempor quam tortor id dolor. Mauris aliquam, nibh vel viverra venenatis, risus sapien ultrices lorem, ac suscipit lacus lorem quis urna. Vestibulum id tortor urna. Cras at mi a dolor aliquam auctor id imperdiet odio. Phasellus sollicitudin iaculis nisl, eget lacinia felis porttitor ac. Nulla congue laoreet rutrum.
                      </p>
                      <p>Donec condimentum viverra faucibus. Aliquam iaculis scelerisque eros ut imperdiet. In odio risus, eleifend nec viverra porttitor, laoreet ut dui. Fusce posuere mauris a nulla fringilla tristique a ac libero. Donec in eros quis orci cursus pharetra. Nam eu odio sed orci molestie ultricies ac quis felis. Nullam hendrerit, elit sit amet scelerisque porttitor, ligula enim feugiat dolor, quis scelerisque libero libero in nulla. Phasellus hendrerit, sapien id rhoncus accumsan, neque arcu auctor orci, ac luctus nibh ipsum quis risus.
                      </p>
                      <p>Morbi nulla ligula, feugiat sit amet tincidunt sed, cursus a mi. Aenean aliquam tortor quis nisl convallis nec elementum mauris tempor. Aenean non laoreet magna. Phasellus at dolor magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla luctus fringilla mi posuere tempus. Quisque in dolor id nulla vestibulum posuere et sed purus. In lacus sapien, porta id pellentesque sed, iaculis vitae arcu. Etiam rutrum, ante eu tristique consectetur, augue nulla ultrices turpis, quis hendrerit velit quam non massa. Sed vitae eros ac nisl gravida pretium eu tempor mi. Vivamus tristique leo ac augue auctor interdum. In sit amet leo nisi. Fusce a sem leo. Suspendisse at odio neque. Donec consectetur libero vel ipsum dignissim sed vulputate nisi pretium. Morbi in diam lacus, vel mollis libero.
                      </p>
                      <p>Etiam fermentum commodo euismod. Mauris lacinia imperdiet augue, sit amet lacinia tortor placerat vel. Suspendisse pretium, est ac rutrum volutpat, arcu dui fermentum nisl, ac laoreet lectus est et ligula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla convallis, tellus sit amet bibendum dictum, nisl tortor facilisis ligula, at tempor nisl nibh et diam. Sed elementum rhoncus posuere. Pellentesque libero odio, placerat non laoreet vitae, fermentum id mi.
                      </p>
                      <p>Duis vitae erat massa, in consectetur velit. Duis quis ipsum sit amet dolor dignissim iaculis non vitae nibh. Quisque sed sapien sapien, et fringilla eros. Suspendisse porta nisi ut felis sodales eu adipiscing enim volutpat. Nulla porta mauris vitae metus viverra mollis. Nam condimentum elementum augue sed posuere. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean mi lorem, feugiat blandit vestibulum vel, ornare at neque. Fusce nec elit vel ante sollicitudin imperdiet quis non eros. Curabitur sed commodo lectus. Maecenas vitae aliquam lectus. Ut quis diam non dui tempor consectetur. Curabitur vel turpis dui. Aenean gravida porta enim, ut congue lectus ornare a.
                      </p>
              </div>
              <div id="contentRight">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed dui enim. Aenean mattis massa nec quam viverra ut consectetur turpis lobortis. Aliquam vitae elit erat, ac iaculis nunc. Maecenas fringilla ornare blandit. Nunc fermentum bibendum mattis. Curabitur elementum commodo volutpat. Ut dapibus odio sit amet leo euismod in viverra mi cursus. Quisque commodo velit accumsan lorem sagittis dignissim fermentum nisl dapibus. Praesent in augue sem, id viverra enim.
                      </p>
                      <p>Fusce scelerisque, ante in lacinia cursus, sem nulla suscipit magna, at posuere magna tellus sit amet erat. Vivamus erat enim, elementum sed molestie id, mollis eu dolor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque interdum rutrum nisl in aliquet. Nunc bibendum eros non purus gravida venenatis. Duis dictum commodo lorem non sodales. Nunc mattis hendrerit suscipit. Fusce lacinia, mauris a iaculis pharetra, ante massa bibendum augue, nec tempor quam tortor id dolor. Mauris aliquam, nibh vel viverra venenatis, risus sapien ultrices lorem, ac suscipit lacus lorem quis urna. Vestibulum id tortor urna. Cras at mi a dolor aliquam auctor id imperdiet odio. Phasellus sollicitudin iaculis nisl, eget lacinia felis porttitor ac. Nulla congue laoreet rutrum.
                      </p>
                      <p>Donec condimentum viverra faucibus. Aliquam iaculis scelerisque eros ut imperdiet. In odio risus, eleifend nec viverra porttitor, laoreet ut dui. Fusce posuere mauris a nulla fringilla tristique a ac libero. Donec in eros quis orci cursus pharetra. Nam eu odio sed orci molestie ultricies ac quis felis. Nullam hendrerit, elit sit amet scelerisque porttitor, ligula enim feugiat dolor, quis scelerisque libero libero in nulla. Phasellus hendrerit, sapien id rhoncus accumsan, neque arcu auctor orci, ac luctus nibh ipsum quis risus.
                      </p>
                      <p>Morbi nulla ligula, feugiat sit amet tincidunt sed, cursus a mi. Aenean aliquam tortor quis nisl convallis nec elementum mauris tempor. Aenean non laoreet magna. Phasellus at dolor magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla luctus fringilla mi posuere tempus. Quisque in dolor id nulla vestibulum posuere et sed purus. In lacus sapien, porta id pellentesque sed, iaculis vitae arcu. Etiam rutrum, ante eu tristique consectetur, augue nulla ultrices turpis, quis hendrerit velit quam non massa. Sed vitae eros ac nisl gravida pretium eu tempor mi. Vivamus tristique leo ac augue auctor interdum. In sit amet leo nisi. Fusce a sem leo. Suspendisse at odio neque. Donec consectetur libero vel ipsum dignissim sed vulputate nisi pretium. Morbi in diam lacus, vel mollis libero.
                      </p>
                      <p>Etiam fermentum commodo euismod. Mauris lacinia imperdiet augue, sit amet lacinia tortor placerat vel. Suspendisse pretium, est ac rutrum volutpat, arcu dui fermentum nisl, ac laoreet lectus est et ligula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla convallis, tellus sit amet bibendum dictum, nisl tortor facilisis ligula, at tempor nisl nibh et diam. Sed elementum rhoncus posuere. Pellentesque libero odio, placerat non laoreet vitae, fermentum id mi.
                      </p>
                      <p>Duis vitae erat massa, in consectetur velit. Duis quis ipsum sit amet dolor dignissim iaculis non vitae nibh. Quisque sed sapien sapien, et fringilla eros. Suspendisse porta nisi ut felis sodales eu adipiscing enim volutpat. Nulla porta mauris vitae metus viverra mollis. Nam condimentum elementum augue sed posuere. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean mi lorem, feugiat blandit vestibulum vel, ornare at neque. Fusce nec elit vel ante sollicitudin imperdiet quis non eros. Curabitur sed commodo lectus. Maecenas vitae aliquam lectus. Ut quis diam non dui tempor consectetur. Curabitur vel turpis dui. Aenean gravida porta enim, ut congue lectus ornare a.
                      </p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Footer goes here.
</div>

</body>
</html>



* {margin:0;padding:0;} 

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}

#topContentWrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%
    height: auto;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    min-height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: purple;
}

#topContent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 140px;
    right: 0px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

#heading {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 92px;
    width: auto;
    border:2px dashed green;
}

#navbar {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    border:2px dashed red;
    z-index: 1;
}

#totalContentWrap {
    //position: absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;                  /* must be same height as the footer */
    top: 220px;
    left: 140px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}


#contentWrap {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:clip;
    top: 140px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    /*padding-bottom: 100px;                    /* must be same height as the footer */
    background-color: yellow;
}

#mainContent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 140px;
    right: 0px;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;                  /* must be same height as the footer */
    background-color: green;
}

#blank {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 140px;                           /* must be same width as the logo */
    background-color: orange;
    z-index: 3;
}

#contentLeft {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: purple;
    z-index: 2;
}

#contentRight {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -100px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 100px;
    clear:both;
    background-color: orange;
} 

p {
    text-indent:30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left:  20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Show us your CSS for the footer and maybe the body too.

Answer (score 0):

your code was too messy for me, so i re-wrote it to let you better understand whats going on.
Basically there are some small advices to not dive into issues like this:

-you don't need to declare EVERY SINGLE POSITION for your DIVs, just let the default position (which is `static`) do his job.

-Also try to build your site with relative positions if needed (especially with fluid layouts), unless an absolute/fixed position is ABSOLUTELY necessary. you can learn about the definitions of the `position` property [**HERE**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position)

-nest your divs smartly and use margins and float to avoid/permit empty spaces.

-try to keep your code as clean and light as possible.

as you can see, following this little precautions, the CSS became more light and comprehensible:

```
    body, html {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
p {
    padding:15px;
}
#headerwrap {
    width:100%;
    height:140px;
    background-color: red;
}
#logo {
    height:140px;
    width:140px;
    background-color:pink;
    float:left;
}
#heading {
    height:100px;
}
#navbar {
    height:40px;
    background-color:green;
}
#heading, #navbar {
    float:left;
    width:calc(100% - 140px);
}
#middlewrap {
    margin-left:140px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom:-100px;
}
#firstcol, #secondcol {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#firstcol {
    background-color:yellow;
}
#secondcol {
    background-color:blue;
}
#pushdown{
    height:100px;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
#footerwrap {
    height:100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

i also made some small modification to your HTML structure.
you can see the whole project in [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MQUf3/2/).
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take the general comments to heart. I didn't know that there was a calc() function. I always felt that there 'should' be, but I've never found one... Thanks. That being said, what you created is almost what I wanted. I'll take a crack at modifying mine tomorrow, but I want the footer to stick to the bottom of the page, not the bottom of the window.

Comment: easier then! i misunderstood your question. i updated my answer with the right code and an updated fiddle that fit your request. Cheers.

Comment: I know it's been awhile. I've been on on other things. I finally looked at your code and I believe I get all of it except the pushdown piece. Could you shed some light on why that is there?